# How to shift focus to another textformfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I took two texFormField for two different pages email and password now I want to shift focus from email to password using callback function in FocusNode.

I tried FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocusNode), but it won't work.

```
//email.dart (This page containe only email textfield)
    TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            focusNode: emailNode,
            onFieldSubmitted: (emailNode) {
              setState(() {
                FocusScop.of(context).requestFocus(passwordNode);
              });
            },
            controller: _email.text,
          ),

//password.dart(This page contain onlt password)
    TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            focusNode: passwordNode,
            onFieldSubmitted: (passwordNode) {
              setState(() {
                FocusScop.of(context).requestFocus(passwordNode);
              });
            },
            controller: _email.text,
          ),
```

//Both files are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few mistakes, not sure if those were typos.
`TextEditingController` was not assigned properly and probably also a logic when submitting the password field.
Something like this worked for me:

```
class EmailField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode thisNode;

  const EmailField({Key key, this.thisNode}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EmailFieldState createState() => _EmailFieldState();
}

class _EmailFieldState extends State<EmailField> {
  TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      focusNode: widget.thisNode,
      onFieldSubmitted: (emailNode) {
        setState(() {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus();
        });
      },
      controller: _email,
    );
  }
}

class PasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode thisNode;
  const PasswordField({Key key, this.thisNode}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PasswordFieldState createState() => _PasswordFieldState();
}

class _PasswordFieldState extends State<PasswordField> {
  TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      focusNode: widget.thisNode,
      onFieldSubmitted: (passwordNode) {
        setState(() {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        });
      },
      controller: _password,
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
// create this inside the state
FocusNode _emailNode = FocusNode();
FocusNode _passwordNode = FocusNode();

// use this in your layout e.g. Form -> Column
EmailField(thisNode: _emailNode),
PasswordField(thisNode: _passwordNode),
```

Comment: On a single page, this code works perfectly but I wrote the code on a different page for both because I took that widget as a common widget in my application. So, I'm looking for different methods to solve this task.

Comment: Ah ok, so you have those two text fields as separate files?

Comment: Yes, those two are separated, because it is common in the signUp page and Login Page.

Comment: what to do to shift my focus email to the password textField?

Comment: Can you try it now?

Comment: can you do this task using the callback function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234521/discussion-between-zpouip-and-kodala-parth).

Comment: Thank you @zpouip, your code is successfully worked, I made mistake in the code structure so I didn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Ever you try request focus directly from a related focus node?

```
return TextField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
);

//to make focus go to the TextField try call this.
_changeFocus(){
 myFocusNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: No, It's not working. can you tell me how to request focusNode using the callback function?

Comment: you should show your code to the question.